# WCF DataContract - unable to return complex type

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, ienumerable

I have a WCF service that has methods to return `IEnumerable<T>` collections of objects, and also a complex type, `OrganizationCollection`, which has a few properties, which are each an `IEnumerable<T>` of different types. I believe I've set up my Service Contract correctly, and defined my types `DataContract` / `DataMember` correctly.  The method that returns an `OrganizationCollection` fails with an exception. I know that the method functions since I have unit and integration tests that test it. It's only when running with a live and deployed service that it fails. I've even specified the type as a `ServiceKnownType`, but to no avail. What do I need to do to configure the service to be able to return complex types like `OrganizationCollection`?

Note: The WCF service is running with `basicHttpBinding`, and is housed in a `ServiceHost` in a Windows Service.

> [System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException]  {"An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http://localhost:8799/MyService. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details."} System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException

```
[ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true, AutomaticSessionShutdown = false, InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(OrganizationCollection))]
public class MyService: IClientService
{ 
    // ...
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IClientService
{
    // This works:
    [OperationContract]
    IEnumerable<BookSvc> GetBooks(DateTime sinceDate);

    // This fails, with the above exception:
    [OperationContract]
    OrganizationCollection GetOrganizations(DateTime sinceDate);
}
```

`BookSvc` is defined with `[DataContract]` and each property has `[DataMember]`. This is also true with Teacher and Student classes. The properties are all primitive types. `OrganizationCollection` is defined as:

```
[DataContract]
public class OrganizationCollection
{
    [DataMember]
    public IEnumerable<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public IEnumerable<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: First: Are your `Teacher` and `Student` classes marked as `[DataContract]` as well? Second: Did you try changing the types of your properties to `Teacher[]` and `Student[]`? They need to be fully enumerated anyway before they can be returned over WCF.

Comment: @Douglas, 1. Yes, Teacher and Student are marked as [DataContract]. 2. I can try that, but my methods that do work when I execute also return as IEnumerable<T>, but I do realize they are stand-alone return values and not part of a complex type.

Comment: I am not sure; I’ll leave it up to someone else to give an informed reply. I just suggested something you could try for a quick fix. However, I don’t think `IEnumerable<T>` is a good design choice for this scenario anyway; the complex type should be constrained to hold a _populated_ collection. I would prefer `ICollection<T>` if you want to go for the lowest interface.

Comment: You might want to read here: [Collection Types in Data Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347850.aspx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two options:

1. **Concrete collection type** (List, etc.) should be used as return value to provide  serialization mechanism for WCF ([Collection Types in Data Contracts, MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347850.aspx)).
2. Using **known data types** ([Data Contract Known Types, MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167.aspx)).

Comment: Why is a concrete collection type not necessary when returning IEnumerable<BookSvc> in the GetBooks() method?

Comment: Switching over to a hard List<T> type did the trick. Still curious as to why this was needed. It's probably safest to use List<T> in all cases.

Comment: Glad that it has helped you. Rules are described here: [Collection Types in Data Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347850.aspx).